# PHP: What is scope of require_once() database connection variable across PHP files?

Tags: php, session, require, require-once

I am revising a site written by a different developer who has gone MIA. His extant code runs perfectly on the GoDaddy server where it resides (which has PHP version 5.3.24). I am attempting to run it and debug it on an XAMPP local server on my Windows 8.1 machine; the version of PHP on XAMPP is 5.6.3. The code uses mysqli database queries exclusively.

The problem I'm encountering is a connection include file that establishes a connection to the database for the various queries executed by the various PHP scripts of the site. That include file is always included with require_once(). This works with only about half of the routines. I've discovered that in some of the PHP files I have to change the require_once() to require() so that the database connection is still available.

Why would some PHP files that comprise the site only need require_once() and others need require()? What would cause the connection variables to be lost as the user travels from one part of the site to another?

(I have a similar problem with SESSION variables being available across certain PHP scripts but not in others, despite session_start() being stated explicitly at the top of each PHP script...perhaps there's a common cause for both problems.)

Comment: FYI, regular [scope rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) apply. Is it possible that it's terribly outdated code that relies on *register globals*?

Comment: You're going to need to audit all the entry points (assuming hes not using a front controller type set up so there is a single entry point) and make sure you do your require_once there. If the app isnt too big, you might want to take the time to refactor it now... sounds like its got a really crappy architecture.

Comment: Are you using an MVC framework (Codeigniter, Laravel etc) or is it just plain PHP? This is indeed related to variable scope and you can easily test this by writing `global $connection`. This will work. Replace $connection with your variable name (please post some code as well).